# jQuery How to apply text() to a variable

Tags: jquery

I would like to apply the jQuery text() method in order to escape html content containing characters like < or >
This same content is "prepended" to a div block, that is why I need < and > to be escaped

I can't figure out how to do so in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/n28uf/2/

```
<div class="container"></div>

jQuery(function(){
    var  content = '<hello world>';
    jQuery('.container').prepend(content); 
    // Where should I apply the .text() method?
});
```

I tried this:

```
    jQuery('.container').prepend(jQuery.text(content));
```

but I get this error message:

```
    Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n28uf/2/ any idea of what change I should bring to the code to have it working properly?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about prepending a wrapper div and then populating that using `.text()`?

```
jQuery(function(){
    var  content = '<hello world>';
    jQuery('.container').prepend('<div class="foo"></div>');
    jQuery('.foo').text(content);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AfW5k/

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the content to a temporary jQuery object using `text()` to escape it.
2. Retrieve the escaped content from the temporary object using `html()`.
3. Prepend the escaped content to the container.

Sample code:

```
<div class="container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
    var content = '<hello world>';
    var escapedContent = jQuery('<div></div>').text(content).html();
    jQuery('.container').prepend(escapedContent); 
});
</script>
```

This results in the following generated HTML source code:

```
<div class="container">&lt;hello world&gt;</div>
```

In short, use `text()` to escape the content, and use `html()` to retrieve it without losing the escaped characters.